# Plagiarism Tool Uniqueness Detection

Tags: php, curl

I am building a plagiarsm checking tool for my company but have problems on calculating the uniqueness factor.

Calculation works by searching the snippet into Google using GSERP.  The script then checks if there where results then snippet is not unique.

This is my code;

. . .

```
$snippet = '&quot;' . join(" ", array_slice($contentArray, $start, $limit)) . '&quot;';

$start += $limit;
$end += $limit;
$counter++;

$url = '';
$lang = 'en';

$gserp = (g_serp($snippet, $url, $lang));
$gserpCount = count($gserp);
```

. . .

. . .

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

//helper function -- file_get_contents using curl
function file_get_contents_curl($url, $referer = '', $ua = '') {
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    if ($referer != '') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    }

    if ($ua != '') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

//this is the main function
function g_serp($keyword, $url, $lang = 'en') {
    $results = array();
    $g_url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode($keyword) .
        '&rsz=large&userip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_DDR'] . '&hl=' . $lang;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 64; $i+=8) {
        $start = $i;
        $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //change this into your real domain
        $rawdata = file_get_contents_curl($g_url . '&start=' . $start, $referer, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $decoded = json_decode($rawdata, TRUE); //decode as assoc array

        if (is_array($decoded['responseData']['results'])) {
            $pos = $start;

            foreach ($decoded['responseData']['results'] as $result) {
                //if (substr_count(strtolower($result['url']), $url)) {
//                    $GLOBALS['index'] = $pos + 1;
//                }

                $res['position'] = $pos + 1;
                $res['title'] = $result['titleNoFormatting'];
                $res['url'] = $result['unescapedUrl'];

                array_push($results, $res);

                $pos++;
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

. . .

Anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong or how best I can go about this?

Comment: Hey, I have a bunch of code that isn't working, can I send it to you so you can figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Mikho, I can't see an actual question there. Would you edit it so a specific question is included in the text, otherwise it may be closed as _Not A Real Question_? Thanks.

Comment: @halfer What the tool should really do is check if snippets has results found in Google search.  As I didn't found solutions on retrieving Google results, I used GSERP, and that is the code.  It works but it is not consistent, it has results by now and as tested again or another time there would be no results.  What I am asking is how do I improve my GSERP function so that it will be consistent or maybe, is there another solution for it, retrieving Google search results?

Comment: OK, please put that into your question. I still think that's essentially "please help me design this", which is quite broad and discursive, and as such isn't as focussed a question as we tend to prefer here.

Comment: What you want to achieve and couldn't do with that code?